# Streaming files from EventMachine handler?

Tags: ruby, nio, eventmachine

I am creating a streaming eventmachine server.  I'm concerned about avoiding blocking IO or doing anything else to muck up the event loop.

From what I've read, ruby's non-blocking IO can be used to stream files in a non-blocking way, or I can call next_tick, but I'm a little unclear about which of these approaches is preferable.

Part of the problem is that I have not found a good explanation of non-blocking IO library functions in ruby.

**Short version**:
Assuming a long-lived network IO operation, several wall clock minutes of streaming per file, transfer, what is the best way to do this in eventmachine without gumming up the event loop?

```
  while 1 do
    file.read do |bytes|
      @conn.send_data bytes
    end
  end
```

I understand that the above code will block and I'm wondering what to put in its place.  Also, I cannot use the FileStreamer class that is part of eventmachine as is, because I need to manipulate the data after it's read but before it's sent.

Comment: There is a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645761/how-to-write-large-files-with-ruby-eventmachine

Comment: I have not solved this to my satisfaction, and my interest in a "best practice" solution remains high.  My dilemma is that I would like to be able to perform cpu-intensive operations on the stream in something approaching real time.  Unfortunately this answer may be correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645761/how-to-write-large-files-with-ruby-eventmachine/4655193#4655193

Answer (score 1):

I think you can still use FileStreamer. FileStreamer expects its first argument to be a Connection, but this is a loose contract. As long as you implement the methods that FileStreamer expects, it should work. Take a look at this

https://gist.github.com/f4d997c3eeb6bdc5a9f3

The methods you'll need to handle are `send_data` and `send_file_data`. You can perform your manipulations here. Then pass the result along to EM::Connection.

Also, from my reading of the code, the special property of FileStreamer is that it allocates a memory mapped file (unless the file is small). You could do essentially the same thing by opening a regular Ruby File, reading blocks out of it, doing your manipulation, and emulating the behavior of `FileStreamer.stream_one_chunk`. Which is basically:

- Each iteration must either send some data to the Connection, or reschedule itself using `next_tick`
- Data can be repeatedly written to the Connection until the outbound buffer is full (according to `get_outbound_data_size`)
- Once the file has been fully read, it should be closed (of course)

In fact, it seems to me that you had **better not** use FileStreamer unless your file will comfortably fit in memory.

You can look at the EM::Protocols for ideas about how to transform the data as it is streaming through.